# Estimate respiration rate from a respiration signal

Tags: fft, python, continuous-signals

[image]

I have a respiration signal sampled at frequency 125Hz, can I estimate respiration rate signal at a frequency 1HZ from the respiration signal? Is it possible to use FFT or FFT for this purpose in Python? Please let me know if you have any leads.

Comment: Can you plot an example?

Comment: I have added the respiration signal, on y-axis is the normalized magnitude of the signal. Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: First off, your signal is clipped on top and bottom, but probably still usable.  Second, the rate will vary over time, correct?  So you just want a single average measurement for a given period of sampling?

Comment: Why do you expect a respiration frequency of 1 Hz? It looks  like approximately 0.4 Hz would be a better estimate...

Comment: Have you looked at "https://www.amazon.com/atlas-capnography-B-Smalhout/dp/B0006CMVQI" or some such?  I have had to deal with capnometry; it's not for the light of heart.